# handling passed in parameters in nodejs promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, promise, es6-promise

I am new to Nodejs and javascript developmnet. I recently came across promises and I was wondering how I could get over an issue I was facing.

Here is my code:

```
  for (let j = 0; j < expired_vals.length; j++) {

    var data = {
      'customer-id': expired_vals[j].customer,
      'sound-id': expired_vals[j].id
    };  
    console.log(data)

    getDatabaseTemporaryURL(data).then(function(url) {
      console.log(data)
      if(url) {
       //do stuff with url
      }
    });
 }
```

In the code above the first console.log returns the proper value of datas,

```
{ 'customer-id': 1, 'sound-id': 245 }
{ 'customer-id': 1, 'sound-id': 246 }
{ 'customer-id': 1, 'sound-id': 247 }
{ 'customer-id': 1, 'sound-id': 248 }
{ 'customer-id': 1, 'sound-id': 249 }
```

In the second log I only get the last value repeated,

```
{ 'customer-id': 1, 'sound-id': 249 }
{ 'customer-id': 1, 'sound-id': 249 }
{ 'customer-id': 1, 'sound-id': 249 }
{ 'customer-id': 1, 'sound-id': 249 }
{ 'customer-id': 1, 'sound-id': 249 }
```

I know that this is an issue with my promise chain since getDatabaseTemporaryURL is a promise function.

```
function getTemporaryURL({ data }) {

  const customer_id = data['customer-id'];
  const sound_id = data['sound-id'];
  
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //get presigned url
    //do stuff and resolve
  });

}
```

How can I modify my code so that I can access each correct iteration of data within the .then of getDatabaseTemporaryURL? Or should I move to an async/await situation?

Let me know! Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is your error message, and where does it happen? It's a bit unclear where your getTemporaryURL function comes into the bigger picture.

Comment: there is no error message @anatolhiman. i am just getting the incorrect values of data in the .then sequence after gettemporary url is run. i am only getting the latest valuess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things cause this:

1. `var` creates a function scoped variable
2. `.then()` is called AFTER the entire loop is done so, all your `.then()` handlers will only log the last value that your `data` variable had.

Here's some more detail.  When you use:

```
var data = {...};
```

That creates a single variable with function scope.  Subsequent iterations of the loop just assign to that variable, they don't create a new one.  So, all your iterations of the loop are using the same variable.

It is equivalent to this:

```
  var data;
  for (let j = 0; j < expired_vals.length; j++) {

    data = {
      'customer-id': expired_vals[j].customer,
      'sound-id': expired_vals[j].id
    };  
    console.log(data)

    getDatabaseTemporaryURL(data).then(function(url) {
      console.log(data)
      if(url) {
       //do stuff with url
      }
    });
 }
```

Then, since `.then()` handlers are always called asynchronously after the current Javascript context finishes executing, that means that your `for` loop will finish executing before any of your `.then()` handlers are called.  So, when you `console.log(data)` inside the `.then()` handler, all you will see is the last value that you assigned to `data` in your loop - the value you assigned on the last iteration of the `for` loop.

---

If you want each `.then()` to log the value of the `data` variable for its own iteration of the `for` loop, then use `let` instead of `var`.

```
  for (let j = 0; j < expired_vals.length; j++) {

    let data = {
      'customer-id': expired_vals[j].customer,
      'sound-id': expired_vals[j].id
    };  
    console.log(data)

    getDatabaseTemporaryURL(data).then(function(url) {
      console.log(data)
      if(url) {
       //do stuff with url
      }
    });
 }
```

This will create a separate `data` variable for each iteration of the loop.  `let` gives the variable block scope so that the `data` variable has loop scope, not function scope.

FYI, you should pretty much never be using `var` any more.  Use `let` or `const`.  You can always put a `let` definition at the top of your function if you really want a function-scoped variable.  Otherwise, you can more precisely control the scope of your variables with `const` and `let` which is always a good thing.

Comment: thanks so much for the in-depth explanation! what would be your proposed solution?

Comment: @Juliette - One possible solution already added to my answer.